# What is the fastest way to preprocess data?

Tags: sql, json, csv, highcharts

I have an SQL table with huge amounts of stock data which I am planning to use [Highstock](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock) to graph and chart. I also need to be able to add data to the chart with AJAX.

Originally I was thinking of going with JSON but I found out that Highstock supports [prepocessing from a database](http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing-data-from-a-database) . To get the data into JSON or CSV format, I would have to query from the database and then parse the data with PHP/Javascript, which might be redundant.

Just wondering what would be the most efficient and optimized way to preprocess data? This could be a general question, but for my case I am using Highstock.

I'm also wondering if parsing data on the fly might be faster with a data format like JSON or CSV, rather than SQL? Considering a scenario where a chart loads in view with 1000 points charted, but you can resize the chart to show up to say 100000 points. I think it may be faster to read data from JSON or CSV than to use AJAX and query SQL, would that be correct?

Comment: It looks like the Highstock chart requires all the data it's going to show up front.  So zooming in and out of the chart either means getting all the data up front or performing separate loads and making different charts.  I interpret "preprocessing" as "formatting data for Highstock's consumption".  If you have a service layer to your database that provides JSON, use that.  Otherwise, format the data directly from the result set returned by performing the SQL query.  Generally, the less formatting you have to do to hand it to Highstock, the faster the preprocessing will be.

Comment: I would normally say any heavy lifting of set-based data (such as what you are pulling from the database) should be done on the SQL server side. It was designed to do this type of processing. It really depends on what you are doing in your preprocessing.

Comment: Agree with wergild points.  Calculations on the SQL server, and weather to use JS processing or AJAX depends on how much processing you have to do.  If a lot, server side will be the fastest because browser has limited resources.  You may also want to consider NoSQL solutions to reduce object/format conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Your link to [Preprocessing data from a database](http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing-data-from-a-database) seems quite straightforward.  Maybe I'm not understanding how your data is in the DB.  Do you have to do summaries or other heavy processing before the data can be sent to Highcharts?

If this is the case you may want to build a summary table in which all the computations are performed.  Then it's just a simple query.  Your chart will display much faster than waiting for the DB or service layer to perform the work.

For even faster performance you can store your precomputed data in an in-memory database such as [MemSQL](http://www.memsql.com/). You don't have to wait for the network traffic between the DB and your web server.